# Creating SharePoint List form with HTML

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, list-form, angularjs

I want to create a form to be filled by users and when the form is submitted I will store the input data in a SharePoint list. So far I have been using either default SharePoint list forms or Infopath forms. I'm thinking of replacing this with HTML forms. My plan is like this

1. Create the view with HTML/CSS (Reason: want to make the view very dynamic using jQuery and Angularjs) like generate user inputs on-demand.
2. Submit input data to the list using JSOM.

My concern is if I do this I can only do client-side validation for the input. Does SharePoint handle server-side validation even when we use JSOM to update/add new items? Other than this, what other concerns should I have when I do this? Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, using both JSOM and the Rest OData API, but you´ll have to validate the data on the client, Sharepoint will not handle it.

Comment: Oh I see, that's what I was wondering. So, if I use these approach, the only input validation that takes place is in the client? Isn't that a bad approach in terms of security? I don't understand why CSOM exposes add/edit data functionality but provide no server-side input validation in their ORM for example. Do you recommend say using JSOM with a completely custom form?

Comment: JSOM indeed is a good way to create forms. Sharepoint 2013 itself uses javascript to generate the lists forms. The lack of server-side validation is something that bothers me for a long time.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I felt that too but I was wondering if my approach was wrong. Actually, I find it really bad to create my own custom form build it's logic client side and redirect the user with client-side code to my custom form instead of default forms each time. But I guess this is the only way to do it if I want to do everything purely in SharePoint like updating 2 lists with one form (which I've heard that SharePoint is not a good platform to implement such solutions). It's bad stuff when client directly access the data store.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom list forms using SharePoint Designer.

1. Open SPD
2. Open your Site
3. Choose your List under *Lists and Libraries*
4. Choose *List Form* from the ribbon
5. Define the name and type(new/edit/view) of the new form

You should now see your new form at the bottom-right *Forms* section.

1. Click on your form to edit it
2. Click *Advanced Mode* in ribbon
3. All the code is in asp.net, but it shouldn't be to complex if you're familiar with html. You will find all your properties inside `<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">`
4. Add your custom javascript after `<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>`
5. Add your custom css inside `<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">`
6. Save your new form and set it as default for that type

Comment: My problem with this approach is that this form is too rigid and hard to customise because it's a bound form. For example, imagine I wanted to submit multiple items in one form. Like with a control for the user to "Add another item". Would it still work?

Comment: It is possible, but would be complex this way :) You can also create an .aspx page(your form) and open it in a dialog

Comment: Okay, I understand. I upvoted your answer. I can't really accept it as the answer since it's more of  an opinion. Thanks for taking time to advise on the matter.

Comment: @swdon, have you created the custom html form  already? if yes, can you pls share the code for good looking form?